# Android Phone Support of Depth API

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, augmented-reality, arcore

I am venturing a bit into AR Development (in Unity) for android phones (beginner).
So apparently i need a device which supports: Google Play Services for AR 
(To use ARCoreXR plugin in Unity)
I tried building a minimal test application,
but when building to the phone i get (when the phone runs the app):
"Your device is not compatible with this version"
(when my phone tries to install the latest Google Play Services for AR)
My current phone is Asus ZenPhone Max Pro (M1)
Question 1: I guess I need a more recent phone ?
I am looking to buy: OnePlus Nord CE 2 5G
But from:
From https://developers.google.com/ar/devices#google_play
I see that that exact device is not on the supported list, there is, however.
OnePlus     OnePlus Nord CE     Supports Depth API
OnePlus     OnePlus Nord2 5G    Supports Depth API

Question 2: I guess there is a fair chance that this newer phone is supported, but how to be certain before buying?
I can't seem to get in touch with the google AR dev team for an answer.

Comment: Currently trying to get in touch with OnePlus support. But I guess I could just try to find it in a shop and kindly ask them to try installing Google Play Services for AR :-). The practical solution >_<

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.